# How does a program run in c?

Tags: c

I'm just learning programming with c.
I wrote a program in c that had a bug in the body of the while loop
I did not put `{}`.
The program is as follows, but the question that came to me later is how to run the program in c? Why does error 2 not print while it is before the start of the while loop? If the c language is a compiler, why is it that the error of the whole program is not specified first, and up to line 15 the program is executed without any problems?

```
int main()
{

    int n ,k;
    float d ;
    printf("please write your arithmetic sequence sentences ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    printf("please write your common differences");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("\n");
    printf("please write your initial element ");
    scanf("%f",&d);
    printf("error 1");
    printf("\n");
    printf("error 2");
    printf("number \t sum");
    printf("erorr 3");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (i < n)
        j = d + i*k;
        sum += j;
        printf("%d\t%d",j,sum);
        i++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output of `printf` is often line-buffered. It will print the whole buffered line as soon as an `\n` is in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the program enters an infinite loop:

```
while (i < n)
    j = d + i*k;
```

Since the values of `i` and `n` do not change, the condition never becomes false.

Secondly, the printing sequence:

```
printf("error 2");
printf("number \t sum");
printf("erorr 3");
```

does not display a line break at the end. The output is buffered (stored internally) waiting for the line break to be printed, which, naturally, never happens. Add `\n` at the end of "erorr 3" to see the difference.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why this happened to the third \n? Why didn't happen for the first \n?

Comment: The third is ok. But there is no the forth.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n ,k;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    float d ;

    // If the given values are not an integer, it wouldn't continue the sequence and end as an "error"
    printf("please write your arithmetic sequence sentences ");
    if(scanf("%d",&n)){
        printf("please write your common differences");
        if(scanf("%d",&k)){
            printf("please write your initial element ");
            if(scanf("%f",&d)){
                printf("Number \tSum\n");
            } else {
                printf("error");
            }
        } else{
            printf("error");
        }
    } else{
        printf("error");
    }

    // This is where the values get solved
    // You also forgot to add {} in your while statement
    while (i < n){
        j = d + i*k;
        sum += j;

        printf("%d\t%d",j,sum);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Please don't just post code, add prose that explains what and why you changed.